# Вывести самую длинную строку из массива String. Java

Tags: java

У меня массив строк. Я сделал счетчик символов в каждой из них.

Каким способом мне можно вывести самую длинную строку?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            final String[] words = poem.split("\n");
            int count = 0;// счетчик символов
            for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(words[i] + "символов- " + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У строк есть метод length(). Вам нужно всего лишь пройтись по всем элементам массива, сравнивая их длины и сохраняя элемент с наибольшей длиной.

```
public static void Main(){
    String[] words = poem.split();
    int maxLength = 0;
    String longestWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++){
        if (words[i].length() > maxLength){
            maxLength = words[i].length();
            longestWord = words[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(longestWord);
}
```

Comment: А можете пожалуйста хотя бы примерно продемонстрировать, как будет выглядеть код?

Comment: Код максимально простой, вам нужно добавить только ввод данных и изменить вывод.

Comment: сколько нужно человек, чтобы закрутить лампочку или строк кода, чтобы найти самое больше значение в множестве?))  правильный ответ для 2 случаев - 1 : Arrays.stream(words).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));